# Miller columns in SWT?

Tags: java, swt, miller-columns

Is there an SWT widget that implements [Miller columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns)?

Here is what I mean:

[image]

A kind of recursive master details widget, who add a new column dynamically when the user select an item in the rightest column ?

Comment: I think this is a very concrete and constructive question - likely with a very specific answer. So why is it closed?

Answer (score 3):

The [opal project](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/) has a widget called [`ColumnBrowser`](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/ColumnBrowser).

Here is a screenshot:

[image]